# Difference between directly assigning a float variable a hexadecimal integer and assigning through pointer conversion

Tags: c++, c, pointers, floating-point

I was investigating the structure of floating-point numbers, and I've found that most of compilers use IEEE 754 standard to store floating point numbers.
And when I tried to do:

```c
float a=0x3f520000; //have to be equal to 0.8203125 in IEEE 754
printf("value of 'a' is: %X [%x] %f\n",(int)a,(int)a, a);
```

it produces the result:

```
value of 'a' is: 3F520000 [3f520000] 1062338560.000000
```

but if I try:

```c
int b=0x3f520000;
float* c = (float*)&b;
printf("value of 'c' is: %X [%x] %f\r\n", *(int*)c, *(int*)c, c[0]);
```

it gives:

```
value of 'c' is: 3F520000 [3f520000] 0.820313
```

The second try gave me the right answer. What is it wrong with the first try? And why does the result differ from that when I cast int to float via pointer?

Comment: Welcome to SO. In your first code you assign an integer literal of value 1062338560 to a float variable. That is probably not what you want to do. Such an assignment does not apply any encoding style defined by IEEE 754 but only converts an integer to a float of same value.

Comment: as a side note, IEE-754 representations of `float` and `double` are not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: I hope you will agree that `float a = 1062338560` should assign 1062338560 to `a`, not any other value.  So `float a = 0x3f520000` does exactly the same thing.  Normal operations on floating-point values always operate on the *values*, not on the internal bit-by-bit mantissa-and-exponent structure -- because of course working with the values is what you want the vast majority of the time.  If you want to work with the internal, bit-by-bit structure, you must use other techniques, such as your dodge involving `int b` and casts and pointers.

Comment: Hexadecimal floating point constant values are handled differently in C and C++. Pick *one* language.

Comment: Thank you all very much! You've answered so quick! It makes me feel great)

Comment: Apart from the representation being different, this is also a [strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the first converts the value (`0x3f520000` is the integer 1062338560), and is equivalent to this:

```
float a = 1062338560;
printf("value of 'a' is: %X [%x] %f\n",(int)a,(int)a, a);
```

The second reinterprets the representation of the `int` -  111111010100100000000000000000 - as being the representation of a `float` instead.
(It's also undefined, so you shouldn't expect it to do anything in particular.)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think that I'm assigning an integer value to a float. I've realized that now)

Answer (score 4):

<sub>[Note: This answer assumes C, not C++, which have different rules]</sub>

With

```
float a=0x3f520000;
```

you take the *integer* value `1062338560` and the compiler will convert it to `1062338560.0f`.

If you want hexadecimal [floating point constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant) you *must* use exponent-format using the letter `p`. As in `0x1.a40010c6f7a0bp-1` (which is the hexadecimal notation for `0.820313`).

What happens with

```
int b=0x3f520000;
float* c = (float*)&b;
```

is that you break strict aliasing and tell the compiler that `c` is pointing to a floating-point value (the strict aliasing break is because `b` *isn't* a floating point value). The compiler will then *reinterpret* the bits in `*c` as a `float` value.

Comment: Rather: the strict aliasing violation would mean that further code like `*c = 3.14f; printf("%x", b);` might print `0x3f520000` instead of the floating point representation of `3.14f`, because of the invoked undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

0x3f520000 is an integer constant. When assigned to a float, the integer is converted.

Answer (score 0):

Some more proper example of how to convert in the second case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  uint32_t fi = 0x3f520000;
  float f;
  memcpy(&f, &fi, sizeof(f));
  printf("%.7g\n", f);
}
```

it prints:

```
0.8203125
```

so that is what you expected.

The approach I used is `memcpy` that is the safest for all compilers and best choice for modern compilers (GCC since approx. 4.6, Clang since 3.x) that interpret `memcpy` as "bit cast" in such case and optimize it in a efficient and safe way (at least in "hosted" mode). That's still safe for older compilers, but not nessessarily efficient in the same way; some can prefer cast through union or ever through different pointer type. On dangers of that ways, see [here](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/959) or generally search "type punning and strict aliasing".

(Also, there could be some weird platforms that suffer from endianness issue that integer endianness differs from float one; ones that have byte different than 8 bits, and so on. I don't consider them here.)

UPDATE: I was starting answering to initial version of the question. Yep, bit casting and value conversion will give principally different results. That's how float numbers work.